# Bison cast between expression types

Tags: c, bison, yacc

I have the following bison code, and the following statements work fine.

```
1 + 1
1.0 + 1.0
```

But I want the following statement to work

```
1.0 + 1
```

I understand that the below code is suboptimal, but I was asked to keep it in this format.

```
    %{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <errno.h>

    /* Prototypes */
    int yylex(void);
    void yyerror(char *);

    int isFloat = 0;
    %}

    %union {
        int iVal;
        double fVal;
    }

    %token <iVal> INTEGER
    %token <fVal> FLOAT

    %type <iVal> expri termi utermi factori parti
    %type <fVal> exprf termf utermf factorf partf 

    %%
    command : expri         {printf("%d\n", $1); return;}
            | exprf     {printf("%f\n", $1); return;}
            ;

    expri   : expri '+' termi   {$$ = $1 + $3;}
            | expri '-' termi   {$$ = $1 - $3;}
            | utermi        {$$ = $1;}
            ;
    termi   : termi '*' factori     {$$ = $1 * $3;} 
            | termi '/' factori {$$ = $1 / $3;}
            | termi '%' factori     {$$ = $1 % $3;}
            | factori       {$$ = $1;}
            ;
    utermi  : utermi '*' factori    {$$ = $1 * $3;} 
            | utermi '/' factori    {$$ = $1 / $3;}
            | utermi '%' factori    {$$ = $1 % $3;}
            | '-' factori       {$$ = -$2;}
            | factori       {$$ = $1;}
            ;
    factori : factori '^' parti {$$ = pow($1, $3);}
            | parti         {$$ = $1;}
            ;
    parti   : '(' expri ')'     {$$ = $2;} 
            | INTEGER       {$$ = $1;}
            ;
    /* FLOAT RULES */
    exprf   : exprf '+' termf   {$$ = $1 + $3;}
            | exprf '-' termf   {$$ = $1 - $3;}
            | utermf        {$$ = $1;}
            ;
   termf    : termf '*' factorf     {$$ = $1 * $3;} 
            | termf '/' factorf {$$ = $1 / $3;}
            | termf '%' factorf     {$$ = fmodf($1, $3);}
            | factorf       {$$ = $1;}
            ;
    utermf  : utermf '*' factorf    {$$ = $1 * $3;}
            | utermf '/' factorf    {$$ = $1 / $3;}
            | utermf '%' factorf    {$$ = fmodf($1,$3);}
            | '-' factorf       {$$ = -$2;}
            | factorf       {$$ = $1;}
            ;
    factorf : factorf '^' partf {$$ = pow($1, $3);}
            | partf         {$$ = $1;}
            ;
    partf   : '(' exprf ')'     {$$ = $2;}
            | FLOAT         {$$ = $1;}
            ;
    %%
```

While both types work fine within their own branches, the structure is (clearly) very suboptimal with heavy duplication, but I don't know a work around and I don't know how to cast between them.

Comment: Just do everything as `double`. Integers fit into doublesJust do everything as double. Integers fit into doubles. You will find it basically impossible to handle types within the grammar. van Wijngaarden tried it with Algol-68 and failed completely.

Comment: @EJP, indeed impossible within the language. So you would have to ue a generic `Val` and have more complex `$$` rules, quirying each `$1`, `$3` for their type and emit/perform the appropriate expression. Compilers would generate a structure containing only the appropriate expression to be turned into assembler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few other ways that you could solve this issue:

1. The easiest solution (if you don't need type information) would be to make integers fit in a `double` type, and then you would be able to merge the rules `parti` and `partf`, etc. into one. However, this would really change up the structure, so it might not be what you want.
2. If you need type information, as Paul Ogilvie sugested, you would probably need some `Val` struct that holds a union of an integer/double with a type tag. Again, this might not be what you want because it does require a bit more effort. But...
3. I thought about this a little more, maybe there might be a possible solution that would minimize changes to your existing language format. Essentially, we add "widening" conversion rule(s) from an integer to a float:

   ```
   exprf: /* other exprf rules */
        | expri { $$ = $1; /* Implicit integer widening conversion*/}
   termf: /* other termf rules */
        | termi { $$ = $1; }
   utermf: /* other utermf rules */
         | utermi { $$ = $1; }
   /* ... */
   ```

   This would be a pretty hacky and unwieldy solution because of the resulting reduce-reduce and shift-reduce conflicts that would pop up. (For example the expression `1 + 1` could reduced as `expri` or a `exprf`). You may want to look into [glr-parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/GLR-Parsers.html) and [merging glr parses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Merging-GLR-Parses.html#Merging-GLR-Parses) to fix some of the ambiguities. I hope that this might be something you are looking for.

The first two are more elegant solutions, but perhaps if you really need to, the third option is a viable option, (I advise to use `bison -v` to try to debug these conflicts if you choose this option, and try playing around in bison a bit).